# yocto crops container's PATH variable cannot be modified

Tags: docker, containers, yocto

I have an issue with PATH variable in yocto's crops container. For some not apparent to me reasons this variable is always overwritten, when pokyuser is created. Any other variable can be set normally with standard docker's tricks like ENV or --env or writing to the /etc/environment with RUN echo "VAR=magic_value" >> /etc/environment. But PATH variable just cannot be set. I tried skel directories. I tried even to write in /etc/profile, but nothing. Like there is some kind of black magic that is ignoring completely /etc/environment file. After running env command, the output shows that PATH variable contains /snap/bin in it. I tried to grep it, but again nothing.

My question here will be, how PATH variable can be changed in yocto's crops container for pokyuser?

Important note: it seems, like pokyuser is generated during run-time, so, I cannot even write to the ~/.profile with RUN.

Comment: I stopped using crops which is great but too complicated for me, and now I use [gmacario build-yocto](https://github.com/gmacario/easy-build/blob/master/build-yocto/Dockerfile)

Comment: I tried to use the container you kindly mentioned, but! I ran into a small issue with a shared directory pretty soon after a try to delete any of the directories in that shared directory. The main issue was that those directories belonged to the host user. I think, I missed something in configuration.

Comment: There is no smart management of user rights in this docker as CROPS do, so you need to set folder rights to match jenkins or build users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own Dockerfile based on the crops one, and add things to /etc/skel/ which is the default skeleton directory used for creating the pokyuser.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM crops/poky:ubuntu-16.04
USER root
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar' >> /etc/skel/.bashrc
```